# How to get a large legacy database under version control

Tags: version-control, sql-server-2008-r2, fluent-migrator

I have a inherited large legacy project where there is no version control for the database.
I would like to create fluent migrations and put them under source control to manage this in the future.

My issue is the project is massive. It contains 6 separate databases. Each database contains a lot of businesses logic. ~120,000 stored procedures, triggers & views.
This is too much to be done by hand.

Is there any way to generate a fluent migration from an empty database to a snapshot of production?

Answer (score 2):

If the database allows to create (createtable) scripts, you should be able to use the embedded script feature for it

I would suggest splitting into different migration assemblies (for each db) and using for instance a base namespace (where you only have 1 up/down that executes the embedded script, if you got that you should be able to work with fluentmigrationts syntax for instance in namespace _1 for future changes

See http://tommarien.github.io/blog/2011/12/18/fluentmigrator-part-ii for embeddedscript usage

I hope this helps, but it's gonna take a while to get the base namespace sorted out.